# Convert month text to month number within JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON and I need to convert the month names into number format so "November 2016" would read "11-16" separating the month and year with a dash and only showing the last 2 digits of the year (in Javascript/Jquery). How could I do this please?

```
[
    ["November 2016", "December 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017"],
    ["total", 2, 43, 59, 51, 41],
    ["mammo", 1, 20, 33, 12, 12],
    ["face", 1, 20, 16, 30, 27],
    ["body", 0, 3, 10, 9, 2],
    ["photo", 0, 19, 27, 12, 5],
    ["scan", 2, 24, 32, 39, 36]
]
```

Comment: Either make an array containing the month strings in your language, or cast that string to a date and use `getMonth() + 1`

Comment: is the date array always the first one?

Comment: Yes always first one thanks @Webeng

Comment: Create array or json like : var months = {jan:1, feb:2, mar:3, apr:4, may:5, jun:6};
alert(months.feb); //will shows 2 in message box;

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any library (like moment.js) for ***time*** you need to this with pure js.

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var str = "January 2016";
var arr = str.split(' ');
var month = arr[0];
var year = arr[1];
var newMonth = monthNames.indexOf(month) + 1 ;
var newYear = year % 1000;
if(newMonth<10){
    newMonth = "0" + newMonth
}
alert (newMonth + " - " + newYear);
```

[EX Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4xbzore/)

Comment: I enjoyed the use of `.indexOf` here :). Regarding the module 1000 operation, works well, untill its 2100 :P, but still fine. I just took the last who characters of the string like so: `year[2] + year[3]`. Mine would work until it's year 10000 hahah, though.... module 100 should work better. Why didn't you just do % 100? that makes it work for all future cases.

Comment: Also year is a string, so you would have to do `parseInt(year) % 100`

Comment: @Webeng This is just an example :). After 2099 may be we will use three digits for years :D.

Answer (score 0):

Using MomentJS you could do something like this:

```
var array = [
    ["November 2016", "December 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017"],
    ["total", 2, 43, 59, 51, 41],
    ["mammo", 1, 20, 33, 12, 12],
    ["face", 1, 20, 16, 30, 27],
    ["body", 0, 3, 10, 9, 2],
    ["photo", 0, 19, 27, 12, 5],
    ["scan", 2, 24, 32, 39, 36]
]

for(var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++)
{
    array[0][i] = moment(array[0][i]).format('MM, YY');
}
```

You can get Moment.js here: http://momentjs.com/

its very handy for Date Manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is called `data`, then you could do it as follows:

```
var result = [];
data[0].forEach(function(myString){
    var info = myString.split(" ");
    var month = info[0];
    var year = info[1];
    var mresult;
    switch(month) {
        case "January" : { mresult = 1;  }  break;
        case "February" : { mresult = 2;  }  break;
        case "March" : { mresult = 3;  }  break;
        case "April" : { mresult = 4;  }  break;
        case "May" : { mresult = 5;  }  break;
        case "June" : { mresult = 6;  }  break;
        case "July" : { mresult = 7;  }  break;
        case "August" : { mresult = 8;  }  break;
        case "September" : { mresult = 9;  }  break;
        case "October" : { mresult = 10;  }  break;
        case "November" : { mresult = 11;  }  break;
        case "December" : { mresult = 12;  }  break;   
    }
    result.push(mresult + "-" + year[2] + year[3]);
});
```

and now the array `result` contains all the values as follows:

```
["11-16", "12-16", "1-17", "2-17", "3-17"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether my approach is right or not but we do this,
You need to get each index of array, split it with space, and store month and year in 2 temp variables in every iteration.
Once you have tempMonth and tempYear in variables use below lies to get month in number and year in 2 digits.

```
tempMonth = 'November'
tempYear = '2016'

numMonth = moment ().month(tempMonth).format ('M');
numYear = moment ().year(tempYear).format ('YY');

FinalVar = numMonth + "-" + numYear.
```

Create array again with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is called `data`, then you could just execute:

```
function convert(monthList) {
  monthList.forEach(function (element) {
    var myDate = new Date(element.split(" ")[0] + " 1, 2000");
    var monthDigit = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(monthDigit+"-"+element.split(" ")[1].substring(2,4))
  }, this);
}


convert(data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach using Date.parse and Array#map().

First converts date strings to include a day in format "November 2, 2016" in order to pass to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Use second day of month to avoid any timezone issues

```js
var arr = [["November 2016", "December 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017"],
["total", 2, 43, 59, 51, 41],
["mammo", 1, 20, 33, 12, 12],
["face", 1, 20, 16, 30, 27],
["body", 0, 3, 10, 9, 2],
["photo", 0, 19, 27, 12, 5],
["scan", 2, 24, 32, 39, 36]];

arr[0] = arr[0].map(function(str){  
   var d = new Date(Date.parse(str.replace(' ', ' 2,')));
   return [d.getMonth()+1 ,String(d.getFullYear()).slice(2)].join('-')
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but I gave an upvote for creativity :P. changing it to a fake date (`' 2,'`) so that `Date.parse` works on it, that was enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```js
var array = ["November 2016","December 2016","January 2017","February 2017","March 2017"];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  var str = "1 "+array[i];
  var date = new Date(str);
  var month  = date.getMonth()+1;
  var year = date.getFullYear()+"";
  array[i] = month +"-"+year.substring(2);
}
console.log(array);
```